# Different backup location for DUPLICATE command

Tags: oracle, rman

I am trying to clone a database from one machine to another using the DUPLICATE command in RMAN.  For both machines the OS is Windows 2003 and the database software is 10.2.0.3.  The problem is that my clone only has a C:\ drive and my hosts backups are kept on the L:\ drive.  Is there a way to tell RMAN that the backups it should use for the clone are in a different location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RMAN can [CATALOG](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14194/rcmsynta011.htm#sthref230) the backup pieces in their new location on the new server.  This will allow the duplicate to find them.  I found this solution at [dba-oracle.com](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_rman_clone+copy_database.htm)